# php fastcgi instance failed

Tags: fastcgi, php-java-bridge

Software and Applications installed:

> Windows 7 Professional 64 Bit,
>       WAMP 2.2
>           (Apache 2.4.2,
>           PHP 5.4.3,
>           MySQL 5.5.24),
>       Tomcat 6,
>       JavaBridge 6.2.1 (php-java-bridge_6.2.1_documentation.zip)

With some differences compared to my local PC setup (using Apache 2.2.22 and PHP 5.3.13 and Windows 7 Professional 32 Bit), I've been successfully incorporated all these application to link my PHP to the Java iReport (report builder) through Javabridge, but when I try to do it the same way with our server, accessing `localhost:8080/JavaBridge`, *"PHP FastCGI instance failed"* comes up and trying to configure web.xml to my tomcat and Javabridge directory with some settings from internet search, I'm still with that error.

Hope I deliver myself clear with my query and thanks in advance.